# Calculate the general form of a certain sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can I get the general  form of $a_n$ from the condition：
$$a_{n+1}=-\frac{(a_n+1)^2}{a_n+2}\quad\quad a_1=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: By general form do you mean an iterative sequence?

Comment: Some context would be helpful. What general techniques do you know about for solving recurrences?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a closed form, this is a non-linear relation so not too much hope in this direction.

However for $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ it is possible to find asymptotic behaviour of the sequence.

**I won't enter much into details, here are the main steps:**

For $f(x)=-\frac{(x+1)^2}{x+2}$ we start by searching fixed points.

$f(\ell)=\ell\iff 2\ell^2+4\ell+1=0\iff \ell=-1\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$

Then calculate $f'$, draw the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=x$.

For starting seed $x_0=a_1$ it converges in spiral to $\ell=-1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$.

Now set $b_n=a_n-\ell$ and report into

$f(x+\ell)-\ell=-\dfrac{(2x+3\sqrt{2}-2)x}{2+2x+\sqrt{2}}=\underbrace{(5-4\sqrt{2})}_{\omega}\,x+O(x^2)\quad$  near $0$.

So replace $x=b_n\to 0$ we get $b_{n+1}\sim \omega\,b_n$

> And finally $a_n\approx\ell+\omega^{n-1}(a_1-\ell)+o(w^n)$

Here is a simulation of the first terms, you can see it matches quite well already:

```
                     a(n+1)       l+w^n(a1-l)

                  -.1666666667, -.1568542501
                  -.3787878788, -.3822509940
                  -.2380345511, -.2341981852
                  -.3295134678, -.3314473010
                  -.2691145252, -.2675688062
                  -.3086244497, -.3095276670
                  -.2826103000, -.2819668111
                  -.2996687250, -.3000702760
                  -.2884519634, -.2881789383
                  -.2958144308, -.2959898140
                  -.2909761266, -.2908592072
                  -.2941532070, -.2942292680
                  -.2920659096, -.2920156294
                  -.2934367780, -.2934696670
                  -.2925362391, -.2925145764
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, I

Comment: Maybe it doesn’t have a closed form.

Comment: The best I could get toward a closed form was to set $b_n=a_n+2$ and you get the somewhat simpler $b_{n+1}=4-(b_n+\frac 1{b_n})$. However, I could not progress from there.